# How to solve StaticInjectorError for CalendarWeekHoursViewComponent -> CalendarUtils

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i got the solution but the calnedar looks collapsed any solution to get it done ?
[image]

Comment: Have you added this module in the imports: [] array?

Comment: yeaaaa bro i already did, but still facing this injector issue

Comment: Have you imported it in the correct module?

Comment: Can you also try using CalendarModule.forRoot()?

Comment: bro the error has solved but the thing is that my calendar doesnt look good its totally collapsed

Comment: Please provide the solution that how you have solved it?

Comment: Based on the solution you have provided CalendarModule.forRoot(), but still i cant view the calendar, i was able to see only dates and time that too collapsed each other, any help bro ?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the current calendar view?

Comment: how's it possible to attach screenshot bro ?

Comment: delete question and repost you can see option

Comment: okay bro ill do it

Comment: i added kindly check what's wrong bro